# Using type hints to denote subclass of multiple classes, i.e. `typing.Intersection`?

Tags: python, types, python-typing, static-typing

I am looking for but unable to find a concise way to denote the type hint `obj: "subclass of A and B"`. The type hint `obj: typing.Union[A, B]` does not cover this case as it will accept an instance of A *or* B or any of their subclasses.

I am writing a [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) that can be implemented by classes.
This interface has an `__eq__` method that can compare multiple instances of the same class implementing this protocol. By implementing this protocol, the classes get a default implementation of the `__eq__` method.

```py
import typing

@typing.runtime_checkable
class MyInterface(typing.Protocol):

    def __eq__(o1, o2) -> bool:
        ''' checks if `o1` and `o2` are equal to one another '''
        from random import randint
        return bool(randint(0,1)) # TODO: write a better implementation

    ...
```

I want to add type hints to denote that 1. both objects to `__eq__` must be instances of the same class **and** 2. must implement `MyProtocol`.

Here are the things I have considered:

- One could define a typevar like so: `T = typing.TypeVar('T')` and use that in the signature:

```py
def __eq__(o1: T, o2: T) -> bool:
```

However, this does not enforce implementing `MyProtocol`.

- I could instead be explicit about the protocol:

```py
def __eq__(o1: 'MyProtocol', o2: 'MyProtocol') -> bool:
```

However, this does not prevent the static types from being two different class hierarchies without a shared structure that both implement a protocol (e.g., `BankAccount` implements `HasOpen` and `Door` implements `HasOpen`).

What's a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Pythons type system does not support intersection types